# I want to change state of the component without reloading metro in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

so basically i have bunch of apps in my application
as you can see in image
In my app it check if application is installed or not, if its installed its shows open and if not it shows install now the issue i'm facing is if application is not installed, i click on the button install, it will redirect to play-store then i will install, now whenever i came to my main
page, without reloading metro, the title of button is not updating to open. example. :-
now the last app, i have already installed but title of button is not changed yet.
when i reload the metro it will show open as title, but i want to, without reloading metro, i want change button title.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, Image ,View, Button, Linking } from 'react-native'
    import * as ApkManager from 'react-native-apk-manager';
    import styles from './styles'
    
    class A extends Component {
         constructor(props){
         super(props)
           this.state = {
              title: "Install",
              buttonStatus: false
           }
       }
      
       componentDidMount() {
         console.log("state has been mounted")
          ApkManager.isAppInstalled(this.props.props.packageName).then((data)=> {
          if(data == true){
             this.setState({
                 title: "Open"
             })
          }
        });
       }
    render(){
            return(
             <View style={styles.container}>
              <Image source={{ uri: this.props.props.imageIcon}}
                     style={{width: 100, height: 100, margin: 10}}/>
               <Button style={styles.button}
                  title={this.state.title} 
                  onPress={() => {
                      if(this.state.title == 'Install'){
                        Linking.openURL(this.props.props.storeUrl)
                      }else{
                             this.state.title = 'Open'
                             ApkManager.openApk(this.props.props.packageName);
                    }
                  }}
               />
            </View>
           )
        }
    }
    export default A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setinterval hook to repeat isInstalled method Apkmanager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).